# Public randomization device

Tags: game-theory

I am reading the paper "The Blockchain Folk Theorem"  by Biais et al (2019) (http://publications.ut-capitole.fr/26234/1/32/5/1662/5427771). It is a stochastic game and the authors include a sunspot random variable to "enable players to coordinate their actions using a public randomization device". I went around and tried to look more into this and I couldn't really find any intuitive explanation for what a public randomization device is (there seems to be some information on the mathematical properties of including such a device, specifically the authors reference a paper on noisy stochastic games by Duggan (2012) (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.3982/ECTA10125)).

I guess my question is, could anyone here provide some explanation of this concept? Or even just some reference to better understanding the concept of public randomization devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sunspot is just a publicly observed random variable upon which players can condition their actions (formally it's part of the history of the game).

It's helpful because it is a nice easy way to convexify the set of equilibrium payoff vectors. In many papers (in my experience) it is a convenient assumption that simplifies things, yet may not be necessary--that is the effect of sunspots can be accomplished without their use, it's just more of a hassle.